# how to emit a value with a click event in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am following Vuejs documentation and trying to emit a value with click event.

The code follows:

**Vue Template:**

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <sidebar v-on:incrementBtn="increment += $event"></sidebar>
            <p>{{ increment }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Vue instances:**

```
    Vue.component('sidebar',{
        template:`
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="$emit('incrementBtn', 1)">Increment on click</button>
            </div>
        `,
    });

    new Vue ({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            increment:0
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check [Vue Custom Event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names), Vue always recommends using **kebab-case** for event names.

And as above Vue guide said:

> Unlike components and props, event names don’t provide any automatic
> case transformation. Instead, the name of an emitted event must
> exactly match the name used to listen to that event.

And

> Additionally, v-on event listeners inside DOM templates will be
> automatically transformed to lowercase (due to HTML’s
> case-insensitivity), **so v-on:myEvent would become v-on:myevent – making myEvent impossible to listen to**.

```js
Vue.component('sidebar',{
    template:`
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="$emit('increment-btn', 1)">Increment on click</button>
        </div>
    `
})

new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
    return {
      increment:0
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <sidebar v-on:increment-btn="increment += $event"></sidebar>
            <p>{{ increment }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```