# Dynamically changing props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On my app, I have multiple "upload" buttons and I want to display a spinner/loader for that specific button when a user clicks on it. After the upload is complete, I want to remove that spinner/loader.

I have the buttons nested within a component so on the file for the button, I'm receiving a prop from the parent and then storing that locally so the loader doesn't show up for all upload buttons. But when the value changes in the parent, the child is not getting the correct value of the prop.

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <upload-button
    :uploadComplete="uploadCompleteBoolean"
    @startUpload="upload">
  </upload-button>
</template>

<script>
  data(){
    return {
      uploadCompleteBoolean: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    upload(){
      this.uploadCompleteBoolean = false
      // do stuff to upload, then when finished,
      this.uploadCompleteBoolean = true
    }

</script>
```

**Button.vue:**

```
<template>
  <button
    @click="onClick">
  <button>
</template>


<script>
  props: {
    uploadComplete: {
      type: Boolean
    }

  data(){
    return {
      uploadingComplete: this.uploadComplete
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onClick(){
      this.uploadingComplete = false
      this.$emit('startUpload')
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to emit a value with a click event in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708772/how-to-emit-a-value-with-a-click-event-in-vue-js), so you should use `this.$emit('start-upload')`, then in the template, uses `<upload-button @start-upload="upload"> </upload-button>`

Comment: I do have an emit within `onClick`. My question is how to change the value in the parent and then when passed back as a prop to the child, the child will update accordingly.

Comment: the issue should be `this.$emit('startUpload')` can't be catched by parent component due to the parent component actually listen the event name= **startupload**. so `parement.methods.upload` will not be executed. you can add one console inside `upload()`. if you fix this, it should work fine.

Comment: the parent is able to receive the emitted event and is executing `upload` properly, the issue I'm having is that `uploadingComplete` (in the child component) is not changing back to `true` when the `uploadCompleteBoolean` (in the parent) is changed back to `true` after executing `upload`.

Comment: added one watch to reach the goal. (lol, the naming confused me before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed event name and prop name then it should work.

1. As [Vue Guide: Custom EventName](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) says, Vue recommend always use kebab-case for event names.
   so you should use `this.$emit('start-upload')`, then in the template, uses `<upload-button @start-upload="upload"> </upload-button>`
2. As [Vue Guide: Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) says,

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret
> any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using
> in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents

so change `:uploadComplete="uploadCompleteBoolean"` to `:upload-complete="uploadCompleteBoolean"`

**Edit:** Just noticed you mentioned data property=uploadingComplete.

It is easy fix, add one watch for `props=uploadComplete`.

Below is one simple demo:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('upload-button', {
  template: `<div>  <button @click="onClick">Upload for Data: {{uploadingComplete}} Props: {{uploadComplete}}</button>
         </div>`,
  props: {
    uploadComplete: {
      type: Boolean
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      uploadingComplete: this.uploadComplete
    }
  },
  watch: { // watch prop=uploadComplete, if change, sync to data property=uploadingComplete
    uploadComplete: function (newVal) {
      this.uploadingComplete = newVal
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.uploadingComplete = false
      this.$emit('start-upload')
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      uploadCompleteBoolean: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    upload() {
      this.uploadCompleteBoolean = false
      // do stuff to upload, then when finished,
      this.uploadCompleteBoolean = true
    },
    changeStatus() {
      this.uploadCompleteBoolean = !this.uploadCompleteBoolean
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeStatus()">Toggle Status {{uploadCompleteBoolean}}</button>
  <p>Status: {{uploadCompleteBoolean}}</p>
  <upload-button :upload-complete="uploadCompleteBoolean" @start-upload="upload">
  </upload-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The UploadButton component shouldn't have `uploadingComplete` as local state (data); this just complicates the component since you're trying to mix the `uploadComplete` prop and `uploadingComplete` data.

The visibility of the spinner should be driven by the parent component through the prop, the button itself should not be responsible for controlling the visibility of the spinner through local state in response to clicks of the button.

Just do something like this:

```js
Vue.component('upload-button', {
  template: '#upload-button',
  props: ['uploading'],
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    uploading1: false,
    uploading2: false,
  },
  methods: {
    upload1() {
      this.uploading1 = true;
      setTimeout(() => this.uploading1 = false, Math.random() * 1000);
    },
    upload2() {
      this.uploading2 = true;
      setTimeout(() => this.uploading2 = false, Math.random() * 1000);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <upload-button :uploading="uploading1" @click="upload1">Upload 1</upload-button>
  <upload-button :uploading="uploading2" @click="upload2">Upload 2</upload-button>
</div>

<template id="upload-button">
  <button @click="$emit('click')">
    <template v-if="uploading">Uploading...</template>
    <slot v-else></slot>
  </button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems little bit ambiguë, You can use watch in that props object inside the child component like this:

```
watch:{
    uploadComplete:{
        handler(val){
            //val gives you the updated value 
        }, deep:true
     },
}
```

by adding deep to true it will watch for nested properties in that object, if one of properties changed you ll receive the new prop from val variable
for more information : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

if not what you wanted, i made a real quick example,
check it out hope this helps : https://jsfiddle.net/K_Younes/64d8mbs1/